# SQL: not a single-group group function Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a table like:

```
 A   B   C
101  1  100
101  1  110
101  2  200
202  2  300
202  1  100
303  1  200
303  1  300
```

I am trying to get result like:

```
 A   B   C
101  1  210
202  2  300
303  1  500
```

i tried running this query like:

```
select A, B, max(sum(C))
from table
group by A,B;
```

But still getting error.

```
ORA-00937: not a single-group group function
00937. 00000 -  "not a single-group group function"
```

Can anyone help me out.

Comment: When you use `group by` you must also aggregate by the grouping fields.

Comment: Max regarding to what?

Comment: By the way, your example is also wrong (since you don't have a record `101 1 210`). Sorry, missed the "SUM". Ignore this comment.

Comment: Still a potential error in your example: Are you expecting to get also a record `101 2 200` in your output?

Comment: Your requierment is not clear. What if the source table has also `101  2  10`  row?

Comment: No just want max grouped by A as well as B - @FDavidov

Comment: In that case, I would split the query into two: First (inner) would calculate the sums, second (outer) will only retrieve the max.

Comment: You should describe your expected results *in text too* - don't leave it as a puzzle to us to figure out what that result set means. Please [edit] your question. The confusion in the comments tells you your question is not clear.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done in several ways. This is using a cte (common table expression). The cte does the basic group by, i.e. returns each a/b combination's sum of c.

Then join the cte with a derived table which finds each a's highest sum if c.

```
with cte as
(
    select A, B, sum(C) sumc
    from table
    group by A,B
)
select t1.a, t1.b, t1.sumc
from cte t1
  join (select a, max(sumc) maxc from cte
        group by a) t2 on t1.a = t2.a and t1.sumc = t2.maxc
```